# custom Docker image runs fine in Docker but in Kubernetes is not showing customized data

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, node-red

I have built a Dockerfile from an official image of Nodered and added some custom nodes. After build I ran a Docker container which runs fine and show the custom nodes I added. Now  I pushed the custom image to a private registry and when using it in a kubernetes deployment pods runs fine but the custom nodes are not shown in the Nodered UI.

I have exec into both Docker container and k8s pod to see what was going on and found that the folder 'files' I passed in the Dockerfile to folder /data exists only in the Docker container, it isn´t in the K8s pod.

Here is the folder 'files'in Docker:

```
docker exec -ti ca55c5823200 bash
bash-5.0# cd /data
bash-5.0# ls
files              flows.json         lib                node_modules       package-lock.json  package.json       settings.js
```

Now when I exec into the K8s pod:

```
bash-5.0# cd /data
bash-5.0# ls
config        lib           lost+found    node_modules  package.json  settings.js
bash-5.0#
```

I also checked the pod logs but found nothing useful:

```
k logs nodered-696bc98c7f-c48h7

> node-red-docker@1.3.6 start /usr/src/node-red
> node $NODE_OPTIONS node_modules/node-red/red.js $FLOWS "--userDir" "/data"

20 Sep 18:58:32 - [info] 

Welcome to Node-RED
===================

20 Sep 18:58:32 - [info] Node-RED version: v1.3.6
20 Sep 18:58:32 - [info] Node.js  version: v10.24.1
20 Sep 18:58:32 - [info] Linux 5.4.141-67.229.amzn2.x86_64 x64 LE
20 Sep 18:58:37 - [info] Loading palette nodes
20 Sep 18:58:48 - [info] Settings file  : /data/settings.js
20 Sep 18:58:48 - [info] Context store  : 'default' [module=memory]
20 Sep 18:58:48 - [info] User directory : /data
20 Sep 18:58:48 - [warn] Projects disabled : editorTheme.projects.enabled=false
20 Sep 18:58:48 - [info] Flows file     : /data/flows.json
20 Sep 18:58:48 - [info] Creating new flow file
20 Sep 18:58:49 - [warn] 

---------------------------------------------------------------------
Your flow credentials file is encrypted using a system-generated key.

If the system-generated key is lost for any reason, your credentials
file will not be recoverable, you will have to delete it and re-enter
your credentials.

You should set your own key using the 'credentialSecret' option in
your settings file. Node-RED will then re-encrypt your credentials
file using your chosen key the next time you deploy a change.
---------------------------------------------------------------------

20 Sep 18:58:49 - [info] Starting flows
20 Sep 18:58:49 - [info] Started flows
20 Sep 18:58:50 - [info] Server now running at http://127.0.0.1:1880/
```

This is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM nodered/node-red:1.3.6-12
USER root
COPY files/settings.js /data/
COPY files/ /data/files
RUN chown -R node-red:root /data
RUN bash /data/files/script.sh
```

And this is the Deployment manifest:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nodered
  namespace: nodered
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nodered
  replicas: 1
  template: # template for the pods
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nodered
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nodered
        image: 698364145168.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/nodered:1.0
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /
            port: 1880
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: 300Mi
            cpu: 50m
          limits:
            memory: 300Mi
            cpu: 50m
        volumeMounts:
          - name: config-volume
            mountPath: /data/
      volumes:
        - name: config-volume
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: nodered-pvc
      restartPolicy: Always
```

Any idea what is going on? Thank you in advanced!

After seeing David's comment below I have removed the PV and PVC from the deployment manifest and now I see these syntax errors in the logs. What I don't get is why it is running fine in Docker:

```
k logs nodered-6cdd6954f6-pmgmf

> node-red-docker@1.3.6 start /usr/src/node-red
> node $NODE_OPTIONS node_modules/node-red/red.js $FLOWS "--userDir" "/data"

Error loading settings file: /data/settings.js
/data/settings.js:347
    }
    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/node-red/node_modules/node-red/red.js:136:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
```

Comment: Whatever's in the `nodered-pvc` PersistentVolumeClaim replaces `/data` in the image.  For a new PVC that will initially be empty (it is not initialized with content from the image) so everything that was in the image in that directory will just get lost.

Comment: Thank you David, I have removed the PV and PVC and now I get in the logs a couple of syntax errors. But I don't understand why it is running fine in Docker.

Comment: Docker has a different path to initialize named volumes; but only named volumes and not bind mounts, only on first use and not on updates of the underlying image, only native Docker and not any other container runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the info David. After fixing the syntax errors the application is running and I see in the UI the custom nodes. The problem is that I had to remove the PV and PVC... what would be the best approach to persist data in the same folder I passed config files during the image build? I need to persist  '/data' in an AWS EBS volume.

Comment: Split the code, configuration, and data into separate directories.  Do not mount anything over the code directory (in any environment).  In Kubernetes you can mount a ConfigMap in the configuration directory and a separate PersistentVolumeClaim in the data directory.

Comment: Using AWS EBS volumes for the /data directory is the wrong approach, use a Node-RED Storage Plugin and move the flow storage to a database.

Comment: Thank you hardillb! That seems the right approach!